# Where is the password for newly created EC2 user?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I created a `newuser` on EC2 following this document [AWS doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html). Now I can use this user to SSH to the EC2 instance. The only issue is that every time when I need to use sudo (for example, when I do `sudo yum update`), it asks for password:

```
[sudo] password for newuser:
```

I created a password for `newuser` but this password does not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The procedure given in the article you linked does not have you set a password, so there is no password.

To set a password, login as a user that is allowed to sudo and run:

```
sudo passwd newuser
```

You will have to enter the password for *newuser* twice and then it should be set.

---

### sudo

If you want *newuser* to be allowed to sudo, then you'll have to also edit */etc/sudoers* to add a line such as:

```
# User privilege specification
newuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

That tip is [from here](http://brianflove.com/2013/06/18/add-new-sudo-user-to-ec2-ubuntu/).

Comment: I set a password for `newuser`. I typed this password when asked, it says `newuser is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.`

Comment: Looks like you're going to gitmo! In the meantime, I've updated my answer to explain extending sudo support to a new user. It is not automatically given to users, as it's full admin and doing so would defeat most of the point of even having users.

Comment: Good point. I need to re-think why creating `newuser`.